# How to track dependencies, exceptions and requests for Live Metrics in ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I've configured **Live Metrics** for my **ASP.NET MVC app** with **target framework 4.7.2** using the tutorial given in Microsoft Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream#enable-livemetrics-using-code-for-any-net-application

In this tutorial, they've given a sample `client.TrackDependency()` and `client.TrackRequest()` call in the end. They've also mentioned in comments that those are samples and we must replace it with actual application logic to work. I'm new to all these and I don't know what to replace. Since my application is huge and has a lot of methods, it is impractical to call the tracking methods in each method or controller. Since it is not ASP.NET Core, there are no middlewares and I have to enable Live Metrics by code too. I've added the code in the `Application_Start()` of `Global.asax.cs` of my application, so that it runs during startup.

This is what I've done so far,

```
// Create a TelemetryConfiguration instance.
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfig = Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
telemetryConfig.InstrumentationKey = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppInsightsInstrumentationKey"];
QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor quickPulseProcessor = null;
telemetryConfig.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
    .Use((next) =>
    {
        quickPulseProcessor = new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next);
        return quickPulseProcessor;
    })
    .Build();

var quickPulseModule = new QuickPulseTelemetryModule();

// Secure the control channel.
// This is optional, but recommended.
//quickPulseModule.AuthenticationApiKey = "YOUR-API-KEY-HERE";
quickPulseModule.Initialize(telemetryConfig);
quickPulseModule.RegisterTelemetryProcessor(quickPulseProcessor);

// Create a TelemetryClient instance. It is important
// to use the same TelemetryConfiguration here as the one
// used to setup Live Metrics.
TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfig);

// I need some method by which I can track all the requests, exceptions,
// dependencies etc. here.
```

I searched and searched a lot for a solution but couldn't get a concrete solution. As a last resort I'm requesting you guys to help me. What can I do to track all requests, dependencies, exceptions, etc. globally...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I found out that I can use the `Application_BeginRequest()` event handler to catch all requests inside `Global.asax` itself. All I had to do is to store the `TelemetryConfiguration` into a global variable and access it from the `Application_BeginRequest()` handler. This is what I did:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse;
 
protected void Application_Start()
{
  RegisterLiveMetrics();
  // Omitted the other code for brevity
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var telemetryConfig = Application["TelemetryConfig"] as TelemetryConfiguration;
  TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfig);

  var httpContextCurrent = HttpContext.Current;
  client.TrackRequest(httpContextCurrent.Request.RawUrl, DateTimeOffset.Now, 
  TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(230), httpContextCurrent.Response.StatusCode.ToString(), 
  true);
}

private void RegisterLiveMetrics()
{
  // Create a TelemetryConfiguration instance.
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfig = Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
telemetryConfig.InstrumentationKey = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppInsightsInstrumentationKey"];
QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor quickPulseProcessor = null;
telemetryConfig.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
    .Use((next) =>
    {
        quickPulseProcessor = new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next);
        return quickPulseProcessor;
    })
    .Build();

var quickPulseModule = new QuickPulseTelemetryModule();

quickPulseModule.Initialize(telemetryConfig);
quickPulseModule.RegisterTelemetryProcessor(quickPulseProcessor);

Application["TelemetryConfig"] = telemetryConfig;
}
```

Luckily this seems to work fine. Currently I'm only tracking requests.

Note: I'm not sure about the namespaces mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the ASP .NET MVC with .Net Framework 4.7.2 Version, You need to configure the Application Insights code related to the .NET Specific SDK Type like Framework, Core, Console, etc.

**From the given [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream#get-started), you're following the console app related  app insights code but as you're using the MVC Web App so you need to follow this code from this section of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net).**

**Here is the workaround I tried to get the live metrics, logs in the Application Insights of Azure Portal.**

- In Visual Studio, Created the asp .net mvc web app (.NET Framework version 4.7.2)
- Added the Application Insights Instrumentation Key in the `ApplicationInsights.config`
- Follow the above documentation as it says to create a new folder in the root and add the `ErrorHandler` class and modify the `FilterConfig` class from the ***App_Start*** folder in order to match your `ErrorHandler` Class Functionality.
- And then deploy the MVC Web App. While publishing configure the Application Insights in Visual Studio Publish Window like below:

[image]

After deploying the App, Open the Web App URL in the browser, then you can see the logs in overview tab and also in App Insights Resource Live Metrics Page as you can see the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Hari, Yes I've configured Application Insights using the above mentioned documentation and it is working fine. But when I switch to Live Metrics, it shows that "Your app is offline or you are using an older SDK". I searched with the message on the internet but all results I got are pointing to what I've already done.

Comment: Hello @ArjunDNair, You have used the different codes related to the console app. I have mentioned that you have to use the different code for the ASP.NET MVC Web APP (4.7.2 Framework) given in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net).

Comment: I found out that I need to track the requests using TelemetryClient.TrackRequest for the request to get logged. I also came to know that I can track every request using ActionFilters and I've been trying to set up one for the purpose. I configured the TelemetryConfiguration in Application_Start() method and stored the configuration in a global variable like "Application["TelemetryConfig"] = telemetryConfig", but I'm not able to access it from the custom ActionFilter I've added. When I try to access it, I find it null always. Have you faced such an issue before? If yes then how did you fix it?

Comment: Hi Hari, in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream#enable-livemetrics-using-code-for-any-net-application) which I referred, it says that we can use it to configure Live Metrics for any ASP.NET application. And Live Metrics is enabled by default for .**NET Core** apps. For .NET MVC, we have to enable it using code.

Comment: Yes Arjun, I was saying the same, we have to enable it using code for the .NET MVC Apps and I was not faced custom Action Filters tracking issue previously but I'll try to figure out your issue on my research.

Comment: Ok Hari, Thanks for sparing some of your time for me.

Comment: Hi Hari, I've found a solution myself and I've posted it above.

Comment: Glad @ArjunDNair for resolving the issue!